# How to insert a mathematic formula in a Graphics in TraditionalForm?

Tags: graphics, traditional-form, inset

If a type `Style[x^2 + y^2 <= 9, Red, 20]` I get:

[image]

But if I include that in a plot or graphic, mathematic function appear as:

[image]

How can I get the mathematic formula in previous style?

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the default `FontFamily` used in `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[
 Text[Style[x^2 + y^2 <= 9, Red, 20, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set an option so that all [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) objects in graphics are displayed in "Times" for the duration of the front end session, so that one doesn't have to repeatedly add the [`FontFamily`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily) directive to every graphic:

```
SetOptions[
    $FrontEndSession,
    InsetBoxOptions->{DefaultBaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Times"}}
]
```

For example:

```
Graphics[{Text[x^2+y^2==1]}, PlotLabel->BesselJ[n,x], ImageSize->100]
```

[image]

If you want to make this permanent, then replace [`$FrontEndSession`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$FrontEndSession) with [`$FrontEnd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%5C$FrontEnd). An alternative is to modify the "Graphics" style in the stylesheet.